# SQl Query to Prisma Query

Tags: mysql, orm, prisma, prisma2

I want to convert SQL query (mysql database) into Prisma query. The problem I'm facing is groupby clause. This is my query `SELECT bos.sh_operation_id, bos.sh_shop, bos.app_operation_status, bos.created_at, COUNT(metafields.meta_value) AS meta_value_count FROM bulk_operation_status bos LEFT JOIN metafields ON bos.sh_operation_id = metafields.operation_id WHERE bos.sh_shop = '${session.shop}' AND bos.created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR GROUP BY bos.sh_operation_id, bos.sh_shop, bos.app_operation_status, bos.created_at`

Prisma don't support groupby as of my knowledge. So any help in converting SQL Query into prisma query will be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing